# Apply Custom Function to Pandas Groupby using Rolling 12 Month Window

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by, rolling-computation

I have the following Dataframe, here is a sample:

```
Area    Num Month   Year    Type    Result
AA      1   Jan     2015    A       1
AA      1   Feb     2015    A       2
AA      1   Mar     2015    A       3
AA      1   Apr     2015    A       4
AA      1   May     2015    A       5
AA      1   Jun     2015    A       6
AA      1   Jul     2015    A       7
AA      1   Aug     2015    A       8
AA      1   Sep     2015    A       9
AA      1   Oct     2015    A       10
AA      1   Nov     2015    A       11
AA      1   Dec     2015    A       12
BB      2   Jan     2015    B       1
BB      2   Feb     2015    B       2
BB      2   Mar     2015    B       3
BB      2   Apr     2015    B       4
BB      2   May     2015    B       5
BB      2   Jun     2015    B       6
BB      2   Jul     2015    B       7
BB      2   Aug     2015    B       8
BB      2   Sep     2015    B       9
BB      2   Oct     2015    B       10
BB      2   Nov     2015    B       11
BB      2   Dec     2015    B       12
```

I need to groupby by Columns: `Area`, `Num`, `Type`, `Year` and calculate 90th percentile for each of these groups. I have multiple `Num` and `Type` for each `Area`.

My expected output is:

I need to calculate 12 month percentile value for previous twelve months for each of this group and paste the output in next month.

For example:
Calculate the 90th percentile values for the group with {Area:AA,Num:1,Year:2015,Type:A} and assign it to {Area:AA,Num:1,Year:2016,Type:A,Month:Jan}.

```
Area    Num Month   Year    Type    Result
AA      1   Jan     2016    A       10.9
AA      1   Feb     2016    A       10.99
```

Now for new group(Month February) {Area:AA,Num:1,Year:2016,Type:A,Month:Feb} should calculate the value of 90th Percentile of Result columnn from Feb 2015 to Jan 2016 and so on.

I am finding solution to calculate percentile and groupby individually, but I am stuck as to how to calculate percentile on this moving window.

Comment: (Sorry, this is more of a comment, but I don't have enough rep to comment yet.) Are you aware of the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) `rolling` function? (If so, could you post any code you've tried?) I think `rolling` will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df.Year.astype(str).add("-").add(df.Month.astype(str)).add("-").add(str(1))))
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
df2.groupby(['Area','Num','Type'])['Result'].rolling(12,min_periods=3).quantile(.9).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Area  Num Type       date  Result
0    AA    1    A 2015-01-01     NaN
1    AA    1    A 2015-02-01     NaN
2    AA    1    A 2015-03-01     2.0
3    AA    1    A 2015-04-01     3.0
4    AA    1    A 2015-05-01     4.0
5    AA    1    A 2015-06-01     5.0
6    AA    1    A 2015-07-01     6.0
7    AA    1    A 2015-08-01     7.0
8    AA    1    A 2015-09-01     8.0
9    AA    1    A 2015-10-01     9.0
10   AA    1    A 2015-11-01    10.0
11   AA    1    A 2015-12-01    10.0
12   BB    2    B 2015-01-01     NaN
13   BB    2    B 2015-02-01     NaN
14   BB    2    B 2015-03-01     2.0
15   BB    2    B 2015-04-01     3.0
16   BB    2    B 2015-05-01     4.0
17   BB    2    B 2015-06-01     5.0
18   BB    2    B 2015-07-01     6.0
19   BB    2    B 2015-08-01     7.0
20   BB    2    B 2015-09-01     8.0
21   BB    2    B 2015-10-01     9.0
22   BB    2    B 2015-11-01    10.0
23   BB    2    B 2015-12-01    10.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will work if I have a monthly data. Is there a way to select previous one year if you day wise records instead of monthwise?

Comment: My apologies if the question above was misleading.

Comment: df2.groupby(['Area','Num','Type'])['Result'].resample('MS').rolling(12, min_periods=3).quantile(.9)

Comment: You can do much of the same, create a datetimeindex, then group by the groups you want, next use `resample` to get the datetimeindex into the frequency of months and then use rolling 12 periods at a time.

Comment: df2.groupby(['Area','Num','Type'])['Result'].resample('MS').‌​rolling(12, min_periods=3).quantile(.9) isn't giving me the expected result.   My expected result 1. Need to calculate the 90th percentile of Result Column for a moving Window of 12 Months. The Month Records are not uniform meaning, it does not have 365 day period. Could you throw some light as to how to fix a moving 12 month window. For example Jan 2015 - Dec 2015, Feb 2015 - Jan2016 and calculate 90th percentile for each of this window. Thanks.